# Flutter I want navigate to another screen while the current screen running

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I want navigate to another screen while current screen is running. If in Firestore collection new document add then app listen it and navigate to another page. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the traditional navigator, however, one way of "emulating" something similar is by using an [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html), which keeps both widgets loaded and you can simply select an index. I've used this successfully when I needed a fancy splash screen and wanted my other widget to load early.

However, it seems to me your problem is more to do with maintaining state. I'd recommend reading Flutter's page on [lifting state up](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up). You can use something like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) above your MaterialApp to keep your data loading even when your widget isn't on screen or simply pass your state back and forth between pages using navigator arguments (I don't recommend that).

Comment: Okay it's not problem the current screen is active or not. Actually when new document created in Firestore is there any method to litsen all time Firestore changes? And if changes occur the call screen automatically call even current screen is active or deactive. Please answer me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
void initState() {
    listenFirestore();
    super.initState();
  }
  
 listenFirestore() async {
  Firestore.instance
    .collection('availableDates')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) => {
        // here you can call navigator method
    });
 }
```

Listen to Firebase changes and call a function to navigate for a new screen.

If you are using Flutter Bloc you can do this using `BlocListener`.
BlocListener official [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocListener-class.html).

Comment: I've used but it's not working. And you've used it in init state it will call only once when screen is call.

Comment: `initState` is calling once but `listenFirestore` is listening for the Firestore changes continuously.